# Diferencia Select * y select top 1 en rendimiento

Tags: sql

estoy realizando un curso de SQL y en la explicacion de TOP menciona como es mejor utilizar un Select top 1 para devolver un dato de muchos por ejemplo un tabla como 10 mil campos con valor de 5

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tabla WHERE campo = 5
```

Comprendo que es mejor que un Select * from... al solo devolver el primer resultado encontrado con esa validacion. Pero en el ejemplo que veo hace lo siguiente:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 nombre FROM tabla1 WHERE fechaturno = @fecha)
      INSERT INTO tabla2... VALUES
    ELSE
  PRINT 'EL USUARIO YA EXISTE'
```

En este ejemplo de que manera seria mejor TOP 1 que un SELECT normal en caso de entrar al IF? si a lo que comprendo El Select top 1 al nunca encontrar ningun resultado a lo indicado con WHERE terminaria recorriendo toda la tabla al igual que hubiera hecho el Select *.
Creo que hay algo que no estoy comprendiendo bien pero no le hallo la logica a esta simple consulta

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no entiendes exactamente, si es mejor `SELECT TOP 1 *` y `SELECT TOP 1`? ¿O no entiendes la consulta? De paso, dinos que manejador de BD usas. Conviene que pongas una etiqueta sobre ese manejador en la pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano debe aclarar la base de datos.. pero TOP suele ser Sql server...

Answer (score 1):

Existe una pequeñísima diferencia al momento de compilar, puesto que el compilador convierte el asterisco en una lista con todas las columnas. Eso genera un costo de unos cuantos microsegundos adicionales.

Sin embargo, lo que se incluya en la lista de columnas nunca será evaluado y sólo importa la presencia de las filas. Es más, ni siquiera se necesita el `TOP 1` puesto que se detendrá la búsqueda al encontrar una fila.

De tal forma, puedes escribir algo similar para validar lo que digo.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1/0 FROM tabla1 WHERE fechaturno = @fecha)
      INSERT INTO tabla2... VALUES
ELSE
      PRINT 'EL USUARIO YA EXISTE'
```

Dejo [este artículo de los documentos de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms189259(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) en el que explica el funcionamiento de este tipo de subconsultas. Esto concuerda perfectamente con la prueba que mostré, pero dejo una prueba más clara aquí abajo.

Primero creamos una tabla con varias columnas, un índice clustered y uno non-clustered, además le agregamos sufcientes filas.

```
CREATE TABLE PruebaExists(
    id int identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    fecha date,
    Cadena1 varchar(100),
    Cadena2 varchar(100),
    Valor1  decimal(18,8),
    Valor2  decimal(18,8)
);

INSERT INTO PruebaExists
SELECT  DATEADD( dd, CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 300, GETDATE()),
        CAST( NEWID() AS varchar(100)),
        CAST( NEWID() AS varchar(100)),
        RAND( CHECKSUM( NEWID())) * 1000,
        RAND( CHECKSUM( NEWID())) * 1000
FROM sys.all_columns;

CREATE INDEX IX_PruebaExists_fecha ON dbo.PruebaExists( fecha);
```

Después comprobamos como se ejecutarían estas consultas de forma normal según lo que incluyamos en la lista de columnas.

```
--Con todas las columnas
SELECT *
FROM PRuebaExists
WHERE fecha = '20191223';
--Con una columna indexada
SELECT fecha
FROM PRuebaExists
WHERE fecha = '20191223';
--Con una columna no indexada
SELECT Cadena1
FROM PRuebaExists
WHERE fecha = '20191223';
--Con una constante
SELECT 1
FROM PRuebaExists
WHERE fecha = '20191223';
```

Esto deja claro que cuando se necesita leer una columna que no es parte del índice nonclustered que usamos para el filtro, se tiene que hacer un `Key Lookup` al índice clustered para leer las otras columnas.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después convertimos las consultas a ser parte de EXISTS.

```
IF EXISTS(  SELECT *
            FROM PRuebaExists
            WHERE fecha = '20191223')
    PRINT 'Con asterisco';

IF EXISTS(  SELECT fecha
            FROM PRuebaExists
            WHERE fecha = '20191223')
    PRINT 'Con columna indexada';

IF EXISTS(  SELECT Cadena1
            FROM PRuebaExists
            WHERE fecha = '20191223')
    PRINT 'Con columna no indexada';

IF EXISTS(  SELECT 1
            FROM PRuebaExists
            WHERE fecha = '20191223')
    PRINT 'Con 1';
```

Y así vemos como lo único que se evalua es el índice que usa el filtro ya que no necesitamos el resto de las columnas. Todos los planes de ejecución terminan siendo iguales.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así podemos ver que las columnas o valores no se leen al momento de ejecución y, por lo mismo, se descartan al momento de generar el plan de ejecución desde un inicio.

Comment: El costo no es al compilar, si no al traer los valores. Hay que ver que hace el motor (siempre, en bases de datos siempre el motor decide y no hay una regla escrita), pero va a devolver los campos que pida en el select...

Comment: No, los valores nunca se leen. Solo se valida que exista la fila. Si los valores se leyeran, el código que publiqué generaría un error y no lo hace.

Comment: Dependiendo el motor (por eso digo que no hay reglas claras de esto), puede que el mismo busque si el registro cumple (si es indexados desde el indice, si no va y recupera ese campo) y devuelva (otra vez, depende el motor), contenido del registro entero o solo los campos pedidos o nada como en tu caso. Pero el costo esta en esa devolucion (aunque despues no haga nada con eso que devuelve) porque eso le implica una busqueda en disco